# Postgres filled missing primary key

Tags: postgresql

I have a postgres table, and it's primary key is auto-increment unsigned int. As far as my knowledge of postgres takes me, postgres keeps these auto incrementing values as sequences. So if an entry is deleted from the table, and the specific primary key is dropped, the next inserted row, won't reuse the previously dropped primary key.

Now, the table I mentioned, had the first 6 rows dropped a long time ago, (primary keys : 1,2,3,4,5,6 ), and meanwhile new entries have been inserted, but the strange thing is, that at some point in time,not exactly after the rows were dropped, those first few rows have been filled, and now the primary keys 1 to 6 are in use, even though postgres should have continued on.

At some point in time, we had to deal with some bloating, and we dealt with it by vacuuming, but I do not think that to be the main cause of this issue.

I know this type of question is missing some of the context and is difficult to debug something without actually seeing the problem, but the main issue again is why was the primary key reused?

Hoping someone with more background and understanding on how postgres works might tell me about some hidden mechanics that I am not aware of.

Thanks!

Comment: The **only** job of a primary key is to be unique. Nothing else. The values don't need to be continuous or without gaps. It does not matter at all if that unique value is 1, 43, 38463987432, or -3875. You don't need to do anything, everything is normal.

Answer (score 1):

Even if a column has its default come from a sequence, you can still insert a specific value for it if you want to.  So the most likely explanation is that some obsessive person noticed a gap and decided to fill it to restore balance to the universe.

```
create table foobar (x bigserial, y text);
insert into foobar values (23, 'yes'); --set explicitly
insert into foobar values (default, 'no');
insert into foobar (y) values ('maybe');

select * from foobar;
 x  |   y   
----+-------
 23 | yes
  1 | no
  2 | maybe
```

Or maybe someone reset the sequence to start from 1, and once it collided with existing rows and started throwing errors, they then fixed the problem they created by resetting it back to the max+1.